# Getting probabilities from cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following machine learning pipeline in python using nested cross-validation:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.svm import SVC
sss_outer = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.4, random_state=15)
sss_inner = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=0.2, random_state=16)
pipe_svm = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()), ('clf', SVC(kernel="linear"))])
parameters = {'clf__C': logspace(-4, 1, 50)}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_svm, param_grid=parameters, verbose=1, scoring='roc_auc', cv=sss_inner)
cross_val_score(grid_search, X, y, cv=sss_outer)
```

Now I would like to get probabilities out of cross_val_score so that I can calculate the AUC and drawing the ROC and precision/recall curve. How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried : `cross_val_score(grid_search, X, y, cv=sss_outer, scoring='roc_auc')`

Comment: Yes, but then I'm just getting the AUC as a result but I cannot plot the ROC and precision/recall curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [sklearn.metrics.roc_curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve) function to calculate the ROC score of your model

Here is an example code snippet using SVM classifier:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

X = {
    "train": [...],
    "text": [...]
}


Y = {
    "train": [...],
    "text": [...]
}

sss_outer = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.4, random_state=15)
sss_inner = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=0.2, random_state=16)

pipe_svm = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()), ('clf', SVC(kernel="linear"))])
parameters = {'clf__C': logspace(-4, 1, 50)}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_svm, param_grid=parameters, verbose=1, scoring='roc_auc', cv=sss_inner)

probas_ = grid_search.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

You could also reach to sklearn example: [Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) with cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html) for more details.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your example uses a separate training and test set ("train" and "test"). With this I then have kind of double nested cross-validaton. Is it also possible to do without this explicit training and test set just with nested cross-validation?

Comment: You can do this without splitting beforehand into training and test before doing cross validation, using the cross_val_predict function - see code below. Splitting before you do grid search CV makes doing repeated cross validation on the whole dataset time consuming to code.

Answer (score 1):

```
## 3. set up cross validation method
inner_cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=5)
outer_cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=5)

## 4. set up inner cross validation parameter tuning, can use this to get AUC
log.model = GridSearchCV(estimator=log, param_grid=log_hyper, cv=inner_cv, scoring='roc_auc')

## 5. ordinary nested cross validation without probabilities
log_scores = cross_val_score(log.model, X, Y, scoring='roc_auc', cv=outer_cv)
print("AUC: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (log_scores.mean(), log_scores.std() * 2))

## 6. this is to get the probabilities from nested cross validation 
log_scores2 = cross_val_predict(log.model, X, Y, cv=outer_cv,method='predict_proba')
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(Y, log_scores2[:, 1])
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

You can use the cross_val_predict function to do the nested cross validation and get the probabilities out for a ROC curve. As far as I can see GridSearchCV does not allow extraction of cross validated probabilities like cross_val_predict does.

I assume the values from cross_val_predict are the mean probabilities from all iterations. You can't get the cross validated probabilities from cross_val_score.

Try running negative controls on random data, if your not sure if the method is over-fitting or not. This is good practice.